# How to upgrade datastax enterprise server 3.0.2 to 4.0?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

What is the correct procedure of upgrading Datastax enterprise server. We have the datastax 3.0.2 running and we need to upgrade it to 4.0.1.

Can it be done using the Opscenter UI? Or do I need to manually upgrade the package on each machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pretty good upgrade instructions in the docs: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgradeTo4_0.html

You will need to manually upgrade each node, and it will take two upgrades, as you have to first upgrade to the latest DSE 3.2 release (3.2.6 right now), then upgrade to DSE 4.0 (and you should go to the latest which is 4.0.3 right now)

Comment: Found it already but thanks for pointing to the correct URL.Wish it could be done using Opscenter itself like Cloudera's Cloudera manager.